# React Native Expo - Enlarging Image size causes not all image contained

Tags: react-native, expo

Here's my image component:

```js
<Marker  
  style={{width: this.state.smallItemsSize, height: this.state.smallItemsSize}}
  key={itemInstance.id}
  coordinate={{
    latitude: itemInstance.lat,
    longitude: itemInstance.lng
  }}> 
  <Image resizeMethod='resize' resizeMode="stretch" source={{ uri: `${Constants.manifest.extra.server.baseUrl}${itemInstance.imageUrl}` }} width={50} height={50} style={{width: this.state.smallItemsSize, height: this.state.smallItemsSize}} />
</Marker>
```

When I change the state to a larger number, it will cause as below:

[image: Before enlarged]
[image: Enlarged]

But if I change the state to a smaller number, and then enlarge it again, it's all fine.. Is it a bug or something? As far as I remember it was all fine previously.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue by adding the maximum possible size to the style of marker.